# Mixture of types using string template

Tags: java, stringtemplate

I am using a string template group to create a java source file. Several of the classes extend another class and need to call a super method that can contain a mixture of types, normally `int`, `String` and `Enum`.

```
super(list) ::= <<
super(<stringList(list)>);
>>

stringList(list) ::= <<
<list:{v | <s(v)>}; separator=", ">
>>

s(v) ::= <<
<if (v)><v; format="java-string"><else>null<endif>
>>
```

I have these templates to build a `super` method that just contains Strings. How do I create a template that can handle a mixture of `Strings`, `ints` and `Enums`?

Comment: Can you provide sample output you want?  Also: <list:{v | <s(v)>}; separator=", "> can be <list:s; separator=", ">

Comment: @TheANTLRGuy 
I want to be able to pass in a list of different objects and get something like `super("string", MyEnum.VALUE, 5, null);` 

I think this works for `Enums` and `Strings` though that surprised me as I sort of expected an `Enum` to get formatted as `VALUE` and not `Enum.Value` when using the `s(v)` template.

Comment: doesn't work for nums and null?  Hmm...  BTW,

<if (v)><v; format="java-string"><else>null<endif>

is <v; format="java-string", null="null">

Comment: @TheANTLRGuy One of the problems with this <if (v)><v; format="java-string"><else>null<endif> was that if it gets given a false Boolean it writes null. This <v; format="java-string", null="null"> solves that! Does st#add("something", Object[]) ignore nulls?